# How to create a folder in the SD card which can read or write only with my App?

Tags: java, android, filesystems

I want to create a folder in SD card that only my app can read or write. I don't want the user to have access. Here is my code:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/myfolder");
file.mkdirs();
```

It successfully creates a directory named "myfolder", but everyone can access it.  How can I secure the created folder (or create a secured folder directly)?

Comment: if you use new File, it can be accesed by everyone. make it hidden by adding period (.) at the start of your folder name (i.e : .myfolder) or create the directory with shell command

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira Your answer is just wrong.  A . won't make it hidden from anyone enumerating the directory, and won't give it protection if plugged into an SD card reader

Comment: its hidden in android only, if you plug it into Windows, then it will be visible

Comment: Its not even hidden in ANdroid, ls -a will see it.  So will a program asking for all files in a directory.

Comment: oh yes. ls -a will list that folder. i read the question wrong. so, what about the shell command? is that working?

Comment: I wouldn't want an app writing a folder to my sdcard that I couldn't access.  You would probably make users very mad if you did this and deployed it.

Comment: Android support SQLite database, could you use an encrypted database to store your documents in?

https://www.sqlite.org/android/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki

Comment: @MeasSerey you got some advance? Don't forget check one answer as correct ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can't, not entirely.  ANyone can take out the card, put it into an sd card reader, and read it without any Android checks at all.

Now if all you're worried about is other apps accessing it (and not the phone's owner)-  you need KitKat or above, and files on the SD card are private by default, so long as they aren't put in a public directory.  Pre-4.4, this is just completely impossible the SD card is public territory.

Answer (score 0):

I think encryption is your best friend. You can use [symmetric encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric-key_algorithm) where only your app has the key. As long as your reads/writes are not a lot this should be a fine solution.

Answer (score 0):

With this example you can put your file in the internal storage in one space private to your app.

Writing the file:

```
try {
 OutputStreamWriter fout= new OutputStreamWriter(
 openFileOutput("test.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
 fout.write("This is a test.");
 fout.close();
} catch (Exception ex) {
  Log.e("Files", "Error writing file to internal memory");
}
```

You can find your file in:

> /data/data/java_package/files/test.txt

Reading the file:

```
try {
  BufferedReader fin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(openFileInput("test.txt")));
  String texto = fin.readLine();
  fin.close();
} catch (Exception ex) {
  Log.e("Files", "Error reading file from internal memory");
}
```

Comment: @MeasSerey you got some advance?